# Laravel 5.6 Like Button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm using this package [here](https://github.com/ChristianKuri/laravel-favorite) in Laravel 5.6 to add likes system in my project.

I have updated the models as per their documentation. However, I'm confused on how to use this package.

I have added tried the following which adds the logged in user to the particular article likes list when he visits the link.

```
public function show(ArticleCategory $articlecategory, $slug)
{
    $categories = ArticleCategory::all();
    $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $user = User::first();
    $user->addFavorite($article);
    return view('articles.show', compact('article', 'categories'));
}
```

And in my user dashboard, I'm able to pull up all the articles which are liked by the user with

```
$user = Auth::user();
$favoritearticles = $user->favorite(Article::class);
```

But I'm looking for a functionality where I have a button on the article page where when a logged user clicks on it, he is added to the likes list. I haven't tried this before so stuck at this point.

I replaced

```
$user->addFavorite($article);
```

with

```
$user->toggleFavorite($article);
```

but that just toggles the favourite list. I mean when I visit the link once, the logged in user is added to the likes list. When I visit the link for the second time, the logged in user is removed from the likes list. The cycle is repeated.

Could anyone explain to me how to achieve the like functionality with a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're almost there,
You have to add a `button` and on click you will trigger an AJAX request to the server to perform what you want without refreshing the page, here is an example:

First you'll add a button and give it an ID or class:

```
<button class="like">Like</button>
```

Then the moment you click on it, you'll call the `url` which you need to replace with the route to your function,

Then you have to declare a method like so:

```
public function like($slug)
{
    $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $user = \Auth::user(); //to get authenticated user...
    $user->toggleFavorite($article); // toggle so if u already like it u remove it from the liked table
    return response()->json(['status': 1])
}
```

And of course add the route to your `routes.php`:

```
Router::get('like/{slug}',"ArticleController@like");
```

then add the function (jQuery is used here) to hook the AJAX call

```
$('.like').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'wwww.example.com/articles/slug',
    data: {slug: 'the slug'},
    success: function(data){
      alert('its done')
    },
  });
})
```

Comment: That works like a charm. I have one last question. I have used <a class="btn btn-sm white like" data-toggle-class="primary" data-class="primary"><span class="d-inline"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like</span> <span class="d-none"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up text-white"></i> Liked</span></a> in my article page. When i click on it it adds and when i click on it again it removes the like. But when i refresh the page the button shows like instead of liked. How to make that stay as liked if the user has already liked it

Comment: I'm unable to mention Sletheren in the comment and <code></code> doesn't work for me. Please excuse for the improper alignment of the code in the comment above

Comment: Hello, you can do that by when you load the article page you do inside your blade template something like `@if($post->isFavorited())<button>Unlike</button>@else <button>Like</button>`  hope you get it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a form in you article page with a button

```
<form action="{{url('favorite/{$post->id}')}}" method="post">
@if($post->isFavorited())
<button type="submit">Remove from favorite</button>
@else
<button type="submit">Add to favorite</button>
@endif
</form>
```

create the favorite route and controller

```
Router::post('favorite/{id}',"ArticleController@toggleFavorite");


public function toggleFavorite($id) {
 $article = ArticleCategory::find($id);//get the article based on the id
 Auth::user()->toggleFavorite($article);//add/remove the user from the favorite list
 return Redirect::to('article/{$id}');//redirect back (optionally with a message)
}
```